# android database cursor without required methods such as getBoolean and getDate

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cursor

android database cursor missing common methods such as

```
getBoolean
getDate
getObject
getBigDecimal
```

Why is that?

How to implement these methods? Should I call getString(index) then convert it to the type above? How about getObject()?

Comment: "Why is that?" -- AFAIK, `Cursor` is limited to the data types supported natively by SQLite. "How to implement these methods?" -- that would depend entirely on your database schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primarily because they are not needed and some are also not portable.

- Boolean just use an INTEGER with 0 or 1, you could use masks to have multiple booleans if wanted.
- Date use INTEGER (getLong) or TEXT or REAL.
- Object can potentially be saved as bytes (BLOB) or split into it's components. Noting as an example, that an object in Java, would not be readable/usable in C++, which would then very much contravene portability.
- BigDecimal use REAL (getDouble/getFloat), TEXT or even bytes (BLOB).

Have a read of [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html)  which explains the flexibility of SQLite and Data types.